# Error:RuntimeError: An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase

Tags: python, deep-learning, torchvision

I got error after running the following script:

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

## Import the Stuff

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils import data
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

import cv2

import numpy as np

import csv
```

## Step1: Read from the log file

```
samples = []
with open('data/driving_log.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(reader, None)
    for line in reader:
        samples.append(line)
```

## Step2: Divide the data into training set and validation set

```
train_len = int(0.8*len(samples))
valid_len = len(samples) - train_len
train_samples, validation_samples = data.random_split(samples, lengths=[train_len, valid_len])
```

## Step3a: Define the augmentation, transformation processes, parameters and dataset for dataloader

```
def augment(imgName, angle):
  name = 'data/IMG/' + imgName.split('/')[-1]
  current_image = cv2.imread(name)
  current_image = current_image[65:-25, :, :]
  if np.random.rand() < 0.5:
    current_image = cv2.flip(current_image, 1)
    angle = angle * -1.0  
  return current_image, angle

class Dataset(data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, samples, transform=None):

        self.samples = samples
        self.transform = transform

    def __getitem__(self, index):
      
        batch_samples = self.samples[index]
        
        steering_angle = float(batch_samples[3])
        
        center_img, steering_angle_center = augment(batch_samples[0], steering_angle)
        left_img, steering_angle_left = augment(batch_samples[1], steering_angle + 0.4)
        right_img, steering_angle_right = augment(batch_samples[2], steering_angle - 0.4)

        center_img = self.transform(center_img)
        left_img = self.transform(left_img)
        right_img = self.transform(right_img)

        return (center_img, steering_angle_center), (left_img, steering_angle_left), (right_img, steering_angle_right)
      
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.samples)
```

## Step3b: Creating generator using the dataloader to parallasize the process

```
def _my_normalization(x):
    return x/255.0 - 0.5
transformations = transforms.Compose([transforms.Lambda(_my_normalization)])

params = {'batch_size': 32,
          'shuffle': True,
          'num_workers': 4}

training_set = Dataset(train_samples, transformations)
training_generator = data.DataLoader(training_set, **params)

validation_set = Dataset(validation_samples, transformations)
validation_generator = data.DataLoader(validation_set, **params)
```

## Step4: Define the network

```
class NetworkDense(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(NetworkDense, self).__init__()
        self.conv_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 24, 5, stride=2),
            nn.ELU(),
            nn.Conv2d(24, 36, 5, stride=2),
            nn.ELU(),
            nn.Conv2d(36, 48, 5, stride=2),
            nn.ELU(),
            nn.Conv2d(48, 64, 3),
            nn.ELU(),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64, 3),
            nn.Dropout(0.25)
        )
        self.linear_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=64 * 2 * 33, out_features=100),
            nn.ELU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=100, out_features=50),
            nn.ELU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=50, out_features=10),
            nn.Linear(in_features=10, out_features=1)
        )
        
    def forward(self, input):  
        input = input.view(input.size(0), 3, 70, 320)
        output = self.conv_layers(input)
        output = output.view(output.size(0), -1)
        output = self.linear_layers(output)
        return output


class NetworkLight(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(NetworkLight, self).__init__()
        self.conv_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 24, 3, stride=2),
            nn.ELU(),
            nn.Conv2d(24, 48, 3, stride=2),
            nn.MaxPool2d(4, stride=4),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.25)
        )
        self.linear_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=48*4*19, out_features=50),
            nn.ELU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=50, out_features=10),
            nn.Linear(in_features=10, out_features=1)
        )
        

    def forward(self, input):
        input = input.view(input.size(0), 3, 70, 320)
        output = self.conv_layers(input)
        output = output.view(output.size(0), -1)
        output = self.linear_layers(output)
        return output
```

## Step5: Define optimizer

```
model = NetworkLight()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
```

## Step6: Check the device and define function to move tensors to that device

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print('device is: ', device)

def toDevice(datas, device):
  
  imgs, angles = datas
  return imgs.float().to(device), angles.float().to(device)
```

## Step7: Train and validate network based on maximum epochs defined

```
max_epochs = 22

for epoch in range(max_epochs):
    
    model.to(device)
    
    # Training
    train_loss = 0
    model.train()
    for local_batch, (centers, lefts, rights) in enumerate(training_generator):
        # Transfer to GPU
        centers, lefts, rights = toDevice(centers, device), toDevice(lefts, device), toDevice(rights, device)
        
        # Model computations
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        datas = [centers, lefts, rights]        
        for data in datas:
            imgs, angles = data
#             print("training image: ", imgs.shape)
            outputs = model(imgs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, angles.unsqueeze(1))
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            train_loss += loss.data[0].item()
            
        if local_batch % 100 == 0:
            print('Loss: %.3f '
                 % (train_loss/(local_batch+1)))

    
    # Validation
    model.eval()
    valid_loss = 0
    with torch.set_grad_enabled(False):
        for local_batch, (centers, lefts, rights) in enumerate(validation_generator):
            # Transfer to GPU
            centers, lefts, rights = toDevice(centers, device), toDevice(lefts, device), toDevice(rights, device)
        
            # Model computations
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            datas = [centers, lefts, rights]        
            for data in datas:
                imgs, angles = data
#                 print("Validation image: ", imgs.shape)
                outputs = model(imgs)
                loss = criterion(outputs, angles.unsqueeze(1))
                
                valid_loss += loss.data[0].item()

            if local_batch % 100 == 0:
                print('Valid Loss: %.3f '
                     % (valid_loss/(local_batch+1)))
```

## Step8: Define state and save the model wrt to state

```
state = {
        'model': model.module if device == 'cuda' else model,
        }

torch.save(state, 'model.h5')
```

This the error message:

"D:\VICO\Back up\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "D:/VICO/Back up/venv/Scripts/self_driving_car.py"
device is:  cpu
device is:  cpu
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
exitcode = _main(fd)
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
prepare(preparation_data)
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
_fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
run_name="**mp_main**")
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/VICO/Back up/venv/Scripts/self_driving_car.py", line 165, in 
pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
for local_batch, (centers, lefts, rights) in enumerate(training_generator):
File "D:\VICO\Back up\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 291, in **iter**
mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "D:\VICO\Back up\venv\Scripts\self_driving_car.py", line 165, in 
return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
File "D:\VICO\Back up\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 737, in **init**
for local_batch, (centers, lefts, rights) in enumerate(training_generator):
File "D:\VICO\Back up\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 291, in **iter**
return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
File "D:\VICO\Back up\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 737, in **init**
w.start()
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
self._popen = self._Popen(self)
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
w.start()
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
self._popen = self._Popen(self)
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
return Popen(process_obj)
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 89, in **init**
return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
return Popen(process_obj)
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 46, in **init**
ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 143, in get_preparation_data
_check_not_importing_main()
File "C:\Users\isonata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 136, in _check_not_importing_main
is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')
RuntimeError:
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

```
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Process finished with exit code 1

I am not sure the next step for solving the problem

Answer (score 13):

Solved, simply put :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

To avoiid reloading the modul every loop.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issue and fixed it by setting 'num_workers' parameter in DataLoader back to zero:

```
DataLoader(num_workers=0)
```